# Verbos de ligação (copulativos)?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Na seguintes frases:

> Como vai?
>   Vou bem, obrigado.

O verbo ir parece atuar como verbo de ligação. Uma definição bem comum para verbo de ligação ou verbo copulativo é que se trata de verbo que não indica ação, e sim o estado (ou mudança de estado) do sujeito.

No site [nova escola](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/verbos-ligacao-contexto.htm), Vânia Duarte considera que a classificação de um verbo de ligação dá-se pelo contexto. Ela cita dois exemplos:

> O professor virou uma fera.
>   Vovó caiu doente.

Essa é mesmo a posição consensual das gramáticas (haja visto que elas geralmente listam os verbos ser, estar, permanecer, continuar, andar e parecer como exemplos de verbos de ligação)?

No caso,

> Você foi bem na prova?

seria também o verbo ir como verbo de ligação?

---

#### Nota

O usuário @Artefacto me chamou atenção para o seguinte problema. O verbo ser e ir têm a mesma conjugação no pretérito perfeito. Então, no exemplo, ainda é possível colocar o verbo ir no presente.

> Acha que vou bem nessa prova?

Esse não é o mesmo caso de

> Acha que fui bom para sua vida?

Pois no tempo presente teríamos:

> Acha que sou bom para sua vida?

Comment: Diria que no teu último último exemplo, *você foi boa para sua mãe*, o verbo *ir* não é bem verbo de ligação; é mais verbo ausente :)

Comment: "ser bem"? Querias dizer "você foi bom na prova?"

Comment: @Artefacto Talvez seja um brasilianismo, mas  a expressão é mesmo "você foi bem na prova".

Comment: @Jacinto, foi um erro meu. "foi boa para sua mãe" precisa ser o verbo ser. Se mudar o tempo verbal isso fica evidente.

Comment: Ah é o verbo ir. Nesse caso faz mais algo sentido, embora em não se diga em Portugal (diríamos "a prova correu-te bem", "foste bom na prova", "portaste-te bem na prova").

Comment: @rdllopes Eu compreendi a tua distração. Mas já agora, a tua pergunta é sobre o verbo *ir*. Então ela ficaria mais clara se em vez de teres lá o historial da distração e a frase com o verbo *ser*, tivesses só exemplos com o verbo *ir*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase é-me difícil de analisar porque "você foi bem nessa prova" não se diz em Portugal. Poderia dizer-se "a prova vai bem?", mas não "a prova foi bem?" (aí dir-se-ia "a prova correu bem?"), mas, em todo o caso, o que "vai" é a prova, não a pessoa.

Isto é importante porque o que determina se o verbo é de ligação ou não é se expressa um estado permanente ("ser"), transitório ("estar", "andar"), mudança de estado ("tornar-se", "ficar"), continuidade de estado ("permanecer", "continuar") ou aparência de estado ("parecer").

Vendo alguns exemplos na Internet, como este:

> Ele foi bem na maioria dos jogos, mesmo nos que o Panathinaikos saiu derrotado.

parece-me que o significado é o mesmo de "estar bem" em Portugal. Um exemplo do CETEMPúblico:

> O árbitro Pinto Correia esteve bem durante toda a primeira parte e durante quase toda a segunda.

Aqui "estar" aponta para um estado transitório, portanto será um verbo de ligação. Para não o ser, teria de expressar algum dos seus significados como verbo significativo (encontrar-se num lugar, visitar, custar, ter vestido, etc.).